# Multiple navigation control through dependency injection

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, autofac

My base content class. I used this class as a theme for my project. I do not know this info relevant or not. In here I create an abstract method that would overload the navigation method.

```
public abstract class BaseContentPage : ContentPage
{
    public readonly BaseViewModel BaseViewModel;

    public BaseContentPage(BaseViewModel baseViewModel)
    {
        BaseViewModel = baseViewModel;
    }

    public abstract void Navigate(SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e);
}
```

In my locator where I build the dependency Injection public class Locator. in this class mainly focus on adding this class to the container to make the all code loss coupling

```
    private readonly ContainerBuilder _builder;

    public Locator()
    {
        _builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        RegisterTypes();
        Container = _builder.Build();
    }

    public IContainer Container { get; set; }

    private void RegisterTypes()
    {
        _builder.RegisterType<WardListService>().As<IWardListService>();
        _builder.RegisterType<WardListPageViewModel>();
        _builder.RegisterType<WardListPage>();

        _builder.RegisterType<PatientService>().As<IPatientService>();
        _builder.RegisterType<PatientListPageViewModel>();
        _builder.RegisterType<PatientListViewPage>();

        _builder.RegisterType<PatientDetailsPageViewModel>();
        _builder.RegisterType<PatientDetailsViewPage>();   }
```

In my **app.Xaml.Cs** file

```
 public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();              
        Locator locator = new Locator();
        Container = locator.Container;
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(Container.Resolve<WardListPage>());
    }

    public static IContainer Container;
```

I used this method for navigation in my view code behind page

```
    public async override void Navigate(SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PatientDetailsViewPage patientDetailsViewPage = App.Container.Resolve<PatientDetailsViewPage>();
        patientDetailsViewPage.BaseViewModel.SelectedPatient = e.SelectedItem as PatientViewModel;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(patientDetailsViewPage);
    }
```

This code is working perfectly but this only can navigate to one page.meaning as an example on one page we have two buttons that navigate to two different pages. I don't know how to implement this task using above navigate overloader. How to do it can anyone give suggestion to overcome the problem?. Also, I used autofac for dependency injection Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can define container in your CustomNavigationPage and use in every navigation page instance.

```
public class CustomNavigationPage : NavigationPage
{
   public static IContainer Container;

   public CustomNavigationPage()
   {
       Locator locator = new Locator();
       locator.RegisterTypes();
       Container = locator.Container();
   }
}
```

It is dummy code what i mentioned.

You creating a navigation page that customized. So you can use this navigating your pages for example:

```
CustomNavigationPage.PushASync(new TestPage(Container.Resolve<WardListPage>())):
```

If use this your custom navigation page will be resolve your dependencies every call.

> To improve performance you can register your dependencies with
>   singleton pattern. When the app started, dependencies will be registered.
>   After you use this registered dependencies.

There is an improvement : You define a static locator with singleton pattern it registers dependencies in app.cs

```
public sealed class Locator
    {
    private static Locator locator = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    Locator()
    {
      //your registries
    }

    public static Locator Locator
    {
    get
    {
    lock (padlock)
    {
    if (locator == null)
    {
    locator = new Locator();
    }
    return locator;
    }
    }
    }
    }
```

And your app.cs :

```
 public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();              
        Locator locator = new Locator();
        Container = locator.Container;
        .
        .
    }

    public static IContainer Container;
```

This way you only one time register your dependencies. There is no duplication of code. Only one instance will be used.

Comment: I don't understand how this would help to have multiple navigations.Can you be more specific

Comment: yep, I get it but this can use for only passing simple navigation. what I have is a little bit complex. Without writing another class cannot I refactor navigate method in order to have multiple navigation

Comment: Ahh okay , I have a bad method for your container. You can define a static container to use it in every page.

Comment: my issue with overriding navigates method. the way u suggest is working but it duplicates the code I think.if I can set that into my method it would really help